# UI implementation of personal messaging limits

Tags: user-interface

I have a simple messaging system on my site.  I would like to implement limits on messages. For basic users, users can have store a maximum of `250` messages in their inbox and supporters can store a maximum of `3000` messages.

My question is about the UI aspects.

If a basic user already has 250 messages:

- would you block another user from being able to send them a message until they have deleted some messages?
- Or would you put the new message in a queue and not show it until a user has deleted some messages?
- Would you tell them they have new messages waiting but they can't read them until they've deleted some messages?

What would be your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an automatic delete that the oldest messages are automatically removed when newer messages arrive.

Edit: See comment below.

Also, besides this method, you could make a way to save some messages or make them favorite to prevent auto-deleting them.

Comment: So if they have 250 messages and they receive a new message, I should delete their oldest message to make room and still inform them they're at 100% capacity? or delete many? Thanks

Comment: Yes it worksk at forums sometimes but of course it may depend on the speed of how often messages are read. Users should have a reasonable chance to be able to read their messages. If they get daily 250 messages and are not expected to read them daily then the users will not like this method.

Comment: It's for a dating site - What would you expect to a be a reasonable chance to read their messages? Thanks for your input.

Comment: If someone would get 250 messages and did not read those he/she gets a lot to choose from. Maybe for women it will be reached sooner than for men.

Comment: Interesting points. And when you would tell a user they're reaching their limit? at 80%? thanks! Sorry for all of the questions, I work on the site alone, and so it's good to bounce ideas with someone else.

Comment: No problem ... you could indeed put a warning message that the message box is getting full, 80% seems reasonable. Maybe discrimination is not a good idea, but maybe if you see males and females get different amount of messages, you can make a difference in limitations.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for your advice. Enjoy the rest of your day.